# Which of the following sentence is correct when using would?

Tags: would

I'm struggling to understand the rules that applies to the "would" used in past context. For example, which of the following is correct :

A) Sun developed an open protocol which simply specified the exact message formats that clients and servers **would use** to communicate

or

B) Sun developed an open protocol which simply specified the exact message formats that clients and servers **would have used** to communicate

The book I was reading used the A sentence, which is obviously correct. What about the B?

Comment: _Would have_ refers to actions _before_ the time being referred to. The clients and servers were using the formats at the time the protocol was in use, not at an earlier time.

Comment: A. should be "could use" and B. should be "use." Books are not always correct.

Comment: @MarkHubbard Why do you have different replacements for A and B? They're not independent questions, they're two alternative ways to express the intended thought. The question is which one is correct.